# Highstock : how to add an empty zone after last value

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

With highstock I've tried to find a way to avoid drawing the last point at the rightest zone of the graph, horizontally.

I have a graph that updates every 5 seconds, and I want the latest value always being shown at 3/4 of the graph horizontally, not at the rightest part of the chart.
So I need to have an blank zone on grpah on the right side where nothing is drawn.

I just want to draw the price line only on the right side horizontally.  something a bit like this :

[chart example I wish to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBwhu.jpg)

I've tried to play with points object to generate extra invisible points to make it. But I couldn't find a working visible parameter in points to hide points.

```
/// Trying to hide some points, doesn't seem to work:

    var CHART = $("#container").highcharts();
var POINTS = CHART.series[0].points;
    var nPoint = POINTS.length; // nPoint contain 10% more useless points

    i = nPoint*0.9;   // hide all those useless points

    for (; i<nPoint; i++)
    {
        POINTS[i].isInside = false;
        POINTS[i].isNull   = true;
        POINTS[i].options.visible = false;
        POINTS[i].options.enabled  = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `overscroll` property:

```
xAxis: {
    overscroll: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
},
navigator: {
    xAxis: {
        overscroll: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tqd1abxw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.overscroll

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you